# date picker date selection in Android

Tags: android

i am new in the android development. i want show the date picker in the tablet.
when user click on it a popup will come with date picker.
its currently working properly with the below code

```
 DatePickerDialog dialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(RegistrationCompanyStep2Activity.this,new OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
                        {

                            yearExpiration = year;
                            monthExpiration = monthOfYear + 1;
                            dayExpiration = dayOfMonth;
                            spinCompanyEstablished.setText(String.valueOf(yearExpiration)+ "-"+ String.format("%02d", monthExpiration)+ "-" + String.format("%02d", dayExpiration));
                            editCompanyTypeID.requestFocus();
                            openKeyBoard(editCompanyTypeID);
                        }
                    }, yearExpiration, monthExpiration, dayExpiration);
            dialog1.show();
```

Now i want to put some limitation in this.
Like user cant select the future date
so can you tell me what changes i have to do to fulfill my requirements ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use

dialog1.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());

Answer (score 0):

use this **dialog1.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());**